# Function to search for weekends left in month

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a function that returns true or false depending upon whether there are any weekend days left in the month.  Is there a better/cleaner way that I can write this?

```
function checkWeekendsLeft(month, year) {
  var iDaysInMonth   = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  var iCurDayInMonth = new Date().getDate();
  var x              = new Date();
  var weekends       = [];

  if (iDaysInMonth >= iCurDayInMonth) {
    for(var i = iDaysInMonth; i >= iCurDayInMonth; i--) {
      var iDayofMonth = i;
      var date = new Date(year, month - 1, iDayofMonth);
      var iDayOfWeek = date.getDay();
      if(iDayOfWeek === 6 || iDayOfWeek === 0) {
        weekends.push(iDayOfWeek);
      }
    }
    if(weekends.length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `return weekends.length > 0;` instead of that unnecessary if-statement

Comment: Or `return !!weekends.length;`

Comment: Or just return true when you find a weekend: `if(iDayOfWeek === 6 || iDayOfWeek === 0) return true;`.  No need to fill an Array.

Comment: Don't forget that there's a case where you don't `return` anything, not sure whether this was intentional.

Comment: Also, I would think you would either pass a full date to the function, or pass no date at all and use the current date.  Do you really need to know whether some arbitrary month in some arbitrary year has weekends left based on the day of the current month?

Comment: ^ Also, one other obvious thing - if you find a Sunday or a Saturday, you don't need to continue looking, you can exit immediately. In fact, you can limit the iterations to a maximum of 5 - if you are checking the final stretch of the month (say, May 26th) that's the only real time that requires verification. Since you know you will definitely encounter a weekend if the period you're checking is 6 days or more, then you can just forego going over each date.

Comment: Another thing I thought of - you don't need to generate a new `Date` object every time, either. Generate the first one which would give you the starting week day and then just increment that value, no need to re-make the Date when it's only ever going to give you the next number.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this :

```
function hasWeekendDaysLeft() {
  var today = new Date();
  var lastDayInMonth = new Date(today.getYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
  var numToday = today.getDate();

  return lastDayInMonth - numToday > 6 - today.getDay();
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution. Although depending on the exact requirements, it might be off by 1 - if you check `hasWeekendDaysLeft` for the last Sunday of the month it reports `false`. Whether that's valid or not will depend if you consider the _current_ day "upcoming" or not. Which is a very widely encountered problem with dates, so, it's not an _issue_ as much as in need of clarification. Other than that, it's not bad.

Comment: This could be optimised a little to first test `!(numToday%6) || ...` so that if *today* is Saturday or Sunday it immediately returns true (presuming that's the required logic of course…).